# parsing large JSON with java/GSON, can't read the JSON structure

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse, using Java and GSON, a large (about 10GB) database dump in JSON format from the Musicbrainz.org

the JSON file has this structure. No '[' ']' to indicate that this is gonna be an array of objects, and no ',' between each object. Don't know why, but this JSON file is just like that.

```
{
    "id": "d0ab06e1-751a-414b-a976-da72670391b1",
    "name": "Arcing Wires",
    "sort-name": "Arcing Wires"
}
{
    "id": "6f0c2c16-dd7e-4268-a484-bc7b2ac78108",
    "name": "Another",
    "sort-name": "Another"
}
{
    "id": "e062b6cd-5506-47b0-afdb-72f4279ec38c",
    "name": "Agent S",
    "sort-name": "Agent S"
}
```

and this is the code that I'm using:

```
        try(JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(jsonFilePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        jsonReader.beginArray();
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            Artist mapped = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Artist.class);
            //TODO do something with the object
            }
        }
        jsonReader.endArray();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the class that I mapped is this:

```
public class Artist {

@SerializedName("id")
public String id;
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
@SerializedName("sort-name")
public String sortName;
```

}

the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
at DBLoader.parse(DBLoader.java:39)
at DBLoader.main(DBLoader.java:23)
```

I believe that the GSON expect a different structure from what I declared, but I don't understand how should I define this kind of JSON with no commas and no brackets.
Any clues?
thanks

Comment: It's NOT JSON, it's a bunch of separate JSON objects crammed into a file together.  Asking a JSON parser to read it is going to fail.  Same as asking your friend, who speaks English and Spanish, to translate something in Russian for you.  You have a couple of choices: Pre-process the stream and convert it to legal JSON by inserting the missing syntax.  Or, process each valid chunk (a single JSON object between `{...}`) separately.  Do you really need to load the entire thing into memory?

Comment: Sorry, but the message is crystal clear. You order parser to read array, but there's no array, and the parser is giving you the exact problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON by default declares one top value only (and yes, this would be a *valid JSON document*), but there is *JSON streaming* that uses arbitrary techniques to concatenate multiple JSON elements into a single stream assuming that the stream consumer can parse it ([read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming)). Gson supports a so-called lenient mode that turns off the "one top value only" mode (and does some more things irrelevant to the question) for `JsonReader`: [`setLenient`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient-boolean-). Having the lenient mode on, you can read JSON elements one by one, and it turns out that this mode can be used to parse/read *line-delimited JSON* and *concatenated JSON values* since they are simply delimited by zero or more whitespaces that are ignored by Gson (therefore more exotic *record separator-delimited JSON* and *length-prefixed JSON* are unsupported). The reason of why it does not work for you is that your initial code assumes that the stream contains a single JSON array (and it does not obviously: it is supposed to be a stream of elements that does not conform the JSON array syntax).

A simple generic JSON stream support might look like this (using Stream API for its more rich API than `Iterator` has, but it is fine to show an idea, and you can easily adapt it to iterators, callbacks, observable streams, whatever you like):

```java
@UtilityClass
public final class JsonStreamSupport {

    public static <T> Stream<T> parse(@WillNotClose final JsonReader jsonReader, final Function<? super JsonReader, ? extends T> readElement) {
        final boolean isLenient = jsonReader.isLenient();
        jsonReader.setLenient(true);
        final Spliterator<T> spliterator = new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(final Consumer<? super T> action) {
                try {
                    final JsonToken token = jsonReader.peek();
                    if ( token == JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT ) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    // TODO: read more elements in batch
                    final T element = readElement.apply(jsonReader);
                    action.accept(element);
                    return true;
                } catch ( final IOException ex ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        };
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false)
                .onClose(() -> jsonReader.setLenient(isLenient));
    }

}
```

And then:

```java
JsonStreamSupport.<Artist>parse(jsonReader, jr -> gson.fromJson(jr, Artist.class))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (assuming `Artist` has Lombok-generated `toString()`):

> Artist(id=d0ab06e1-751a-414b-a976-da72670391b1, name=Arcing Wires, sortName=Arcing Wires)
> Artist(id=6f0c2c16-dd7e-4268-a484-bc7b2ac78108, name=Another, sortName=Another)
> Artist(id=e062b6cd-5506-47b0-afdb-72f4279ec38c, name=Agent S, sortName=Agent S)

How many bytes does such an approach, JSON streaming, save so that it is used at the service you're trying to consume? I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `jsonl` format where every line is a valid JSON object. (read more [here](https://jsonlines.org/))
You can read file line by line and convert to object. I think it will works.