# Java : OutOfMemoryError even after using GSON Streaming API

Tags: java, gson, out-of-memory, streaming

I have been working on a problem statement where we have a huge JSON response coming in and when we were parsing it using conventional gson parsing technique, it used to give OutOfMemoryException as this method stores the data in memory before processing it, so as a solution to this i have worked on streaming the JSON response where it won't put everything in memory, so it worked fine till somewhere around 1.6 million records and after that even that broke. So this is the exception we are getting.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

This is the entire code i'm using for this:

```
// Getting reponse into InputStream and casting it to JsonReader object for parsing
InputStream liInStream = luURLConn.getInputStream();
lCycleTimeReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(liInStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Our JSON looks like this:

```
{
"Report_Entry": [
    {
       "key1": "value",
       "key2": "value",
       "key3": "value",
       "key4": "value",
       "key5": "value"
    },
    {
       "key1": "value",
       "key2": "value",
       "key3": "value",
       "key4": "value",
       "key5": "value"
    }
]}
```

Using this object into our parsing method:

```
public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> getcycleTimeMap(JsonReader poJSONReaderObj,
        CycleTimeConstant cycleTimeConstant, int processId) {

    Integer counter = 0;
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> cycleTimeMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> finalcycleTimeMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        CycleTime cycleTime = new CycleTime();

        poJSONReaderObj.beginObject();
        while (poJSONReaderObj.hasNext()) {

            String name = poJSONReaderObj.nextName();
            if (name.equals("Report_Entry")) {
                poJSONReaderObj.beginArray();
                while (poJSONReaderObj.hasNext()) {

                    JsonToken nextToken2 = poJSONReaderObj.peek();
                    if (JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT.equals(nextToken2)) {
                        poJSONReaderObj.beginObject();
                    } else if (JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(nextToken2)) {
                        poJSONReaderObj.endObject();
                    } else {
                        String nextString = "";
                        if (JsonToken.STRING.equals(nextToken2)) {
                            nextString = poJSONReaderObj.nextString();
                        } else if (JsonToken.NAME.equals(nextToken2)) {
                            nextString = poJSONReaderObj.nextName();
                        }

                        switch (nextString) {
                        case "key1":
                            cycleTime.setKey1(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key2":
                            cycleTime.setKey2(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key3":
                            cycleTime.setKey3(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key4":
                            cycleTime.setKey4(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key5":
                            cycleTime.setKey5(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    poJSONReaderObj.endObject();

                    System.out
                            .println("Value of Map is : " + new Gson().toJson(cycleTime) + "counter  : " + counter);
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("Counter : " + counter);
                    cycleTimeMap = (HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>) cycleTimeBpProcessIterator(
                        cycleTime, cycleTimeConstant, counter, processId);
                }
                finalcycleTimeMap.putAll(cycleTimeMap);
            }
        }
        JsonToken nextToken = poJSONReaderObj.peek();
        if (JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(nextToken)) {
            poJSONReaderObj.endObject();
        } else if (JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(nextToken)) {
            poJSONReaderObj.endArray();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("FINAL MAP TO BE LOADED : " + new Gson().toJson(finalcycleTimeMap));

    return finalcycleTimeMap;

}
```

POJO class for handling response:

```
 public class CycleTime {
    
    private String key1 = "";
    private String key2 = "";
    private String key3 = "";
    private String key4 = "";
    private String key5 = "";
    
    
    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }
    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }
    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
    public String getKey3() {
        return key3;
    }
    public void setKey3(String key3) {
        this.key3 = key3;
    }
    public String getKey4() {
        return key4;
    }
    public void setKey4(String key4) {
        this.key4 = key4;
    }
    public String getKey5() {
        return key5;
    }
    public void setKey5(String key5) {
        this.key5 = key5;
    }
    
}
```

I'm not sure what might be a culprit here but seems it is giving the same error, i'm wondering what should be the next approach to avoid this OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual code? `cycleTimeMap` is unused, and `finalcycleTimeMap` is never modified.

Comment: @tgdavies, sorry the code was missing. Have added it now, please check

Comment: Presumably `finalcycleTimeMap` is getting very large. Have you checked how much space it uses?

Comment: We have not extensively checked this but this is something which might be the reason as the data is extremely huge : fyi, we have extracted the json for 1 odd day and the file size is 480MB

Comment: What’s your maximum heap size?

Comment: @tgdavies -Xms512M -Xmx1524M, we have this currently

Comment: People outside India will have hard time understanding what is a "Lakh". So please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: @JamesZ noted, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the entire document into a single object does not mean that the streamed reading would help you.
Moreover, Gson uses streaming under the hood because it is just an optional way of reading and writing.
Your approach, however, is very far from being good:

- Gson things:

  - The main thing is: use Gson properly in full and let it do its job. I couldn't run your code for the JSON document you provided: it works neither for the root JSON object, nor for the only top object entry (so your deserializer is broken due to improper used of the `hasNext` and the `beginObject`/`endObject` pair).
- Common Java things:

  - don't catch exceptions in middle returning a partially composed object (is it correct?);
  - don't use `Throwable.printStackTrace` (use proper logging facilities);
  - if you don't want using loggers, then print it to `System.err` (this is just a proper standard stream for such purposes);
  - `Integer` as a counter is a bad idea because of creating many boxed values, especially for huge documents (use `int` -- it is just fine);
  - `enum` values can (and should be) checked for equality with `==` (it is safe since they are singletons);
  - then, you can use `switch` to for enums too (both shorted, more compile-time safe);
  - don't create `Gson` instances in a loop especially that has that many iterations (`Gson` instances are known to be immutable as thread-safe, but not that cheap at constructing its objects);
  - don't use maps where you can have statically typed plain objects (for good);
  - what's the purposes of returning an always-one-key-value-pair map; (return the value);
- Common design things:

  - use as common types as possible for declarations: not `HashMap`, but `Map` (what if someday you need another map with ordered keys? or what if you don't need a map after all?);
  - inverse dependencies (what if you don't need `CycleTime` with five keys?);
- Streaming things:

  - if it runs in an OOM error, then what's the point of collecting a huge map that obviously cannot fit your app RAM? (use callbacks or promises (pushing approach) to process a single element, iterators or streams (pulling approach), reactive streams (pushing approach), whatever);
  - collect the result only for a small memory foot-print or use aggregation (otherwise you're at risk of having OOM).

This is how you can reduce the memory foot-print by using a pushing approach via callbacks:

```java
@UtilityClass
public final class StreamSupport {

    public static void acceptArrayElements(@WillNotClose final JsonReader jsonReader, final Consumer<? super JsonReader> acceptElement)
            throws IOException {
        jsonReader.beginArray();
        while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
            acceptElement.accept(jsonReader);
        }
        jsonReader.endArray();
    }

}
```

```java
@UtilityClass
public final class CycleDeserializer {

    public static void readCycles(final JsonReader jsonReader, final Consumer<? super JsonReader> acceptJsonReader)
            throws IOException {
        jsonReader.beginObject();
        while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
            switch ( jsonReader.nextName() ) {
            case "Report_Entry":
                StreamSupport.acceptArrayElements(jsonReader, acceptJsonReader);
                break;
            default:
                jsonReader.skipValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        jsonReader.endObject();
    }

}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .disableInnerClassSerialization()
        .create();

@Test
public void test()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = openTheHugeDocument() ) {
        CycleDeserializer.readCycles(jsonReader, jr -> {
            final CycleTime cycleTime = gson.fromJson(jr, CycleTime.class);
            System.out.println(cycleTime);
        });
    }
    // do the simplest aggregation operation: `COUNT`
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = openTheHugeDocument() ) {
        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
        CycleDeserializer.readCycles(jsonReader, jr -> {
            try {
                jr.skipValue();
                count.incrementAndGet();
            } catch ( final IOException ex ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Count = " + count);
    }
    // this will probably fail when the document is huge because it is collected into a single collection
    // (you need to let your JVM use as much RAM as possible if it is a must for you)
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = openTheHugeDocument() ) {
        final Collection<CycleTime> cycleTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        CycleDeserializer.readCycles(jsonReader, jr -> {
            final CycleTime cycleTime = gson.fromJson(jr, CycleTime.class);
            cycleTimes.add(cycleTime);
        });
        System.out.println("Count in list = " + cycleTimes.size());
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the runner above you can choose the way you prefer to process your entries: either a dumb logging, or a simple count, or a simple collect-to operation.

For the pull approach via `Stream` approach please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69282822/12232870